# Can I Sum up properties in an annotate

Tags: django, database, orm, sum

I'm creating a html table in my project that is populated by some sum values from my database, I'm trying to sum (coins_remaining) which is a property of my database model. Coins_remaining is calculated by subtracting (`sum_amount_sold` from `Sale` table) from  (`amount` from `Transaction` table). Is this possible?, if so how would I go about it?

HTML Table below

```
           {% for transaction in transactions %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{transaction.currency}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.sum_amount_purchased}}</td>                
                <td>{{transaction.sum_total_price_purchased}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.sum_total_price_purchased}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Function Below

```
@login_required
def portfolio(request):



    context = {
        'transactions': Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('currency').annotate(

            sum_amount_purchased=Sum('amount'),
            sum_total_price_purchased=Sum('total_price')),
            sum_amount_current=?

    }
    return render(request, 'webapp/portfolio.html', context, {'title': 'Portfolio'})
```

Transaction model below

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin = self.total_price / self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+','+self.currency + ', '+str(self.amount)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('transaction-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    @property
    def coins_remaining(self):
        return self.amount - sum(self.sales.all().values_list('amount_sold', flat=True))
```

Sale model below

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    amount_sold = models.IntegerField()
    total_price_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_sold = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sales")
    amount_per_coin_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+','+str(self.amount_sold) + ', '+self.note

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin_sold = self.total_price_sold / self.amount_sold
        super(Sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sale-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Subquery` for that. **Note:** that you have to use `OuterRef` to get the correct `Transaction`. Couldn't try it out for real, but this is how you can use a `Subquery` to annotate a queryset and use it in a calculation afterwards. I'm not entirely sure if that solves your problem, but here you go:

```py
coins_remaining_query = (
    Sale.objects.filter(transaction=OuterRef("id"))
    .annotate(coins_remaining=Sum("amount_sold"))
    .values("coins_remaining")
)

Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values("currency").annotate(
    sum_amount_purchased=Sum("amount"),
    sum_total_price_purchased=Sum("total_price"),
    coins_remaining=Subquery(coins_remaining_query)
).annotate(sum_amount_current=F("sum_amount_purchased")-F("coins_remaining"))
```

Comment: Thanks @jsbeckr but I'm trying to calculate number of coins remaining which would be sum_amount_current=F("sum_amount_purchased")  - sum(self.sales.all().values_list('amount_sold', flat=True))

Comment: Sorry misread the question. I think you can make a Subquery on `Sale` for that: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/subquery.html

Comment: thanks @jsbeckr. do you know how i would integrate that into this code?